# Looping through awk command using bash in RHEL

Tags: bash, shell, awk, rhel

I am trying to loop through the output of an awk command in bash. I saved the output to a variable and when I loop through, all of the output is saved as one long string instead of each one their own individual index. How would I be able to use each individual string? Any other suggestions? Thanks!

```
variable=`awk -F '$3 > 1000 { print $1 }' < /etc/password | grep -v 'person1\|person2'`

for x in "{$variable[@]}";do
chage -M 60 "$x"
```

Comment: your current code is doing what you've asked it to do, ie, store the entire contents of the `awk|grep` call as a single string in a variable named `variable`; I'm assuming what you really want to do is store the `awk|grep` results as an array of values in an array named `variable` in which case you should modify your code to `variable=( $(awk ... | grep ...) )`; you can then run `typeset -p variable` to display the contents/structure of the array

Comment: You'll want to read http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001

Comment: You never need to use grep when you're using awk. `awk -F: '$3 > 1000 { print $1 }' < /etc/password | grep -v 'person1\|person2` can be written as just one command `awk -F: '($3 > 1000) && ($1 !~ /person1|person2/) { print $1 }' < /etc/password`

Answer (score 0):

On surface, the goal is to run `chage ...` on any user with uid > 1000, excluding two predefined users (person1, person2). Minor fix to the loop should address the problem.

Two minor issues are fixed: the awk is using ':' as field separator, and the bash loop iterate over a simple variable (instead of array). Solution integrate the user filter into awk scripts, eliminating the separate `grep`:

```
user_list=`awk -F: '$3 > 1000 && $1 !~ "$(person1|person2)$" { print $1 }' < /etc/password`

for x in $user_list ; do
    chage -M 60 "$x"
done
```